# I styled focus state for my webpage. But even after I'm done clicking button/link, the focus stays, unless I click whitespaces. How do I make it go?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I've styled the focus state for my webpage to my liking. But now it stays on the buttons/links even when I'm done clicking them. I have to click the blank spaces to make it go away. I only want the focus state to be visible when we use TAB key for shifting focus, and(optional) when the buttons are clicked. How can I do that? Do I need to write some JavaScript for that? Basically I want the focus state to behave in a default way, the way it did before I styled it.

```
*:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5rem rgba(61, 112, 46, 0.5);
}

.cta *:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5rem rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) instead of `:focus`.

Comment: No. That would only add the style once the buttons are clicked. The styling wouldn't show if the focus is shifted from button to button using TAB key only.

Comment: `:focus-visible`?

Comment: Yep. @JaromandaX . That's what I should've gone for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this css selector instead of `*:focus`

```
*:focus-visible{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5rem rgba(61, 112, 46, 0.5);

}
```

Comment: That did bring back the default behavior, but the styling went back to the default outline too.

Comment: try adding an outline and see if it works

Comment: Yep ```:focus-visible``` is what I should've used.